# Где ошибка в коде javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как её исправить?

```html
<HTML>
<head><title>Задание 7</title>
<script>
function f1()
{
setTimeout ("f2()",500);
}
function f2()
{
im.style.width=im.style.width*0.5;
im.style.height=0.5*im.style.height;
im.style.top=document.body.offsetHeight/2-25;
im.style.top=document.body.offsetWidht/2-25;
}
</script>
</head>
<BODY onLoad="f1();">
<img ID="im" src="img1.gif" STYLE="position:absolute;width=100;height=100">
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Я вижу использование `im`, но не вижу его объявления.

Comment: А это разве не оно: ID="im"?

Comment: здесь все неправильно... начинаем сначала (с)

Comment: Нет, `im` может быть любой переменной, чтобы использовать в нужном вам ключе, ее надо объявить.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function f1() {
  setTimeout ("f2()",500);
}

function f2() {
  const im = document.getElementById('im');
  im.style.width = `${im.clientWidth * 0.5}px`;
  im.style.height = `${im.clientHeight * 0.5}px`;

  im.style.left = `${document.documentElement.scrollWidth / 2 - 25}px`;
  im.style.top = `${document.documentElement.scrollHeight / 2 - 25}px`;
}
```

```css
#im {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<HTML>
  <head>
    <title>Задание 7</title>
  </head>
  <body onLoad="f1();">
    <img id="im" src="img1.gif" />
  </body>
</HTML>
```